# UIToolBar is black for a split second on load

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Every time I load up the UIView that holds the UIToolbar below (which is attached to the keyboard), it turns black for a second until the view fully loads, and then turns back to the standard white color. I'm stumped as to why this keeps happening.

Here's how I'm forming the UIToolbar:

```
[self.answerField becomeFirstResponder];
UIToolbar *toolbar = [UIToolbar new];


UIBarButtonItem *sectionButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"§" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil
                                                                 action:@selector(addSectionSymbol:)];
UIBarButtonItem *paraButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"¶" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil
                                                              action:@selector(addParaSymbol:)];
UIBarButtonItem *flexSpacing = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
NSString *infoLabel = @"Select text to italicize. Always use italics.";

UIBarButtonItem *infoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:infoLabel style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

[infoButton setEnabled:NO];

[toolbar  setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sectionButton, paraButton, flexSpacing, infoButton, nil]];
self.answerField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
[toolbar sizeToFit];
```

Any ideas?